# Is setting pin code and fingerprint programatically/from terminal possible?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I would need to turn on pin code and fingerprint security feature on my android device.

It could be done:

- either programatically from java code - if you know class that can handle it, please tell me (e.g. IWindowManagerImpl.java can modify animations on device from java code by reflection if you have permissions)
- by adb shell command which executes during app build - if you know commands how to do it from terminal, please tell me
- any other solution?

I can have every permission there is in my app. I don't care about speed or how clean solution is, it can be also done by reflection.

Has anyone tried that?

Comment: And how would you enroll any fingerprints without any user interaction? Why don't you just launch the Lock Screen & Security activity in the Settings app?

Comment: It is possible from ADB to touch screen programatically: adb -e emu finger touch <finger_id> (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html). Additionally if you use IWindowManagerImpl.java by reflection, you can use dismissKeyguard() method that turns off fingerprint and forces you to enter pin. You can click through pin programatically with usage of UiAutomator. I want to create solution that modifies connected device for tests. I want all device settings to change automatically. I managed to implement some setting changes but I struggle with security features.

Comment: Do you think it is doable to simulate a fingerprint action directly in a physical device, instead of emulator?

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to make your application a DeviceAdmin App. Such apps can set/enforce security policies for the device and enabling the pin code is one of them.

For the full list of policies you can enforce see the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#policies).
Unfortunately I have not seen any fingerprint related policies.